# can i fetch and populate different fields using function(data) jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

i want to populate two fields when some one fill up card no.

```
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" Value="<?php echo $grow['name']; ?>">
 <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-control" Value="<?php echo $grow['address']; ?>">
```

but this code populate field one by one. can any one suggest be better code for populating two fields from database. Thank you

**jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#krishi").keyup(function()
{
var k=$(this).val();
var q="name";


$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "getresult.php",
data: 'k='+k+'&q='+q,
cache: false,
success: function(data)
{
    if(data){
    $("#name").val(data);
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "getresult.php",
data: 'k='+k+'&q=address',
cache: false,
success: function(data)
{
    if(data){
    $("#address").val(data);

    }

    } 
});
    }else
        $("#name").val("");
    $("#address").val("");
    } 
});

});



});
</script>
```

**getresult.php**

```
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include("mysql.php");


$k=$_POST['k'];
$q=$_POST['q'];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from inward where krishi='$k'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row[$q]; 


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extract both name and address from database and json them

```
$k=$_POST['k'];
$q=$_POST['q'];
$sql=mysql_query("select address,name from inward where krishi='$k'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$result = array(
               'name'=>$row['name'],
               'address'=>$row['address']);
echo json_encode($result);
```

After that parse them via jquery

```
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "getresult.php",
data: 'k='+k+'&q=address',
cache: false,
success: function(data)
{
    if(data){
    var parsedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $("#name").val(parsedData.name);
    $("#address").val(parsedData.address);

    }

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#krishi").keyup(function()
    {
    var k = $(this).val();
    var q = "name";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "getresult.php",
        data: 'k='+k,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var jsonArr = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(typeof response =='object')
            {
                $("#name").val(jsonArr.name);
                $("#address").val(jsonArr.address); 
            }
            else
            {
                $("#name").val("");
                $("#address").val("");  
            }
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include("mysql.php");

$k   = $_POST['k'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from inward where krishi='$k'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo json_encode(array('name' => $row['name'], 'address' => $row['address']); 
?>
```

Comment: please accept my answer if you think it is useful. I also applied check for JSON data.